# Setting compiler.theme option for Halo/Flex 4 in FlashDevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flashdevelop, halo

Here's what works with ant build.xml:

```
<mxmlc file="${module.main.dir}/main.mxml" keep-generated-actionscript="false" output="${module.output.dir}/main.swf" fork="${flex.fork}">
    <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
    <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
    <compiler.theme file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/themes/Halo/halo.swc"/>
</mxmlc>
```

I tried the following values in Project > Properties > Compiler Options > Additional Compiler Options but none of them worked:

```
-theme=PATH_TO/halo.swc
-compiler.theme=PATH_TO/halo.swc
-theme=file=PATH_TO/halo.swc
-compiler.theme.file=PATH_TO/halo.swc
-theme.file=PATH_TO/halo.swc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
-compatibility-version=3
```

should fix it

or you could try

```
-theme=../frameworks/themes/Halo/halo.swc
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't want compatibility-version=3. I only want to use halo as the theme for my Flex 4.x app. Unfortunately, I don't have a FlashDevelop setup right now so I'm unable to verify the -theme option. But based on my original post, I've already tried that flag with FlashDevelop but was not able to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

copy and paste the below line in additional compiler option.

-theme=${flexlib}/themes/Halo/halo.swc

This will work.